# JDK logger API by default

Tags: quarkus

I am a bit puzzled with the default logging feature. I created a brand new project from scratch and I realised that it shows up the JDK options. I believe this is not what the default behaviour displays on in your documentation [Configuring Logging](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#supported-logging-apis) .

Maybe I am doing something wrong in which case, please let me know how to change to JBoss logging API.

By the way, I was wondering whether the Log4j2 can be plugged in with/without using the SLF4J.

Congratulations for the Quarkus framework, the more I dive in into the framework the more interesting it becomes!. Awesome, cheers!

Using:

- Quarkus 1.6.1
- VSCode
- OpenJDK 11

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The logging documentation has been enhanced and easier support for Log4J2 has been provided. This will be available in the upcoming 1.7 version which should be available very soon.

You can find here the future version of the documentation: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/logging.adoc

What you show us is the autocomplete feature coming from your IDE Quarkus plugin, it shows only the JUL level whereas we prefere the Apache one.
You may see with the Quarkus Plugin support team if they can change this.

Comment: excellent news!. Looking forward for it.
I inclined to say the problem is is a bit further down. If I set the property: quarkus.log.console.level=DEBUG, the logger doesn't pick up the value of this property and it doesn't log anything below to level=INFO. Thank you folks for your quick response.

Comment: I used `quarkus.log.console.level=DEBUG`  very often and it works. There should be something somewhere else. If you have a reproducer you can open an issue or link it here so I can have a look

Comment: I am sorry, It worked. I've just added my category to the property file and it did the magic. The only remaining thing is the plugin which hints JUL log level instead. cheers